# is there any MCU based on cortex-A who's on-chip mask primary bootloader can be changed?

Tags: arm, embedded

I want study cortex-A inside. but AM335X and S5PV210's inside flash can not be changed, so I want to know if there is there any MCU based on cortex-A who's on-chip mask primary bootloader can be changed?

please recommend some for me, if there has.

please forgive my pool English, thank you!

Comment: http://ti.com/launchpad   the hercules is based on the cortex-r which is basically two cortex-a's in lock step for safety.   most boards have an off chip rom you can re-write (raspberry pi, ntc chip, pine 64, beaglebone, and so on (some on board some in an sd card some both)).  In general the cortex-a is not the kind of thing you use as an mcu, esp with the cortex-m4, cortex-m7 and the cortex-m8 that is on its way.

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to study and what on board read only memory has to do with it.  the rom is not related to the cortex-a core.  is it the cortex-a you want to study or some chip with a rom independent of the core used?

Comment: It sounds to me like they want a Cortex-A with a modifiable on-chip flash (ie, like little Cortex-M type MCUs typically have).  Why they want that is unclear.  But rather than shopping for a chip alone, someone without a lot of background or only a preliminary need will probably end up selecting an existing evaluation board or product to re-purpose - at least trying to design or commission a custom board for a chip selected in isolation without the guidance of deep awareness from working with existing ones would be unwise.

Comment: If the goal is just to run code to "study" the chip by running small custom bare metal programs on it, selecting something with a little on-chip RAM to which code can be uploaded via JTAG might be workable.  Typically such a system will use external SDRAM but some systems designed for external main memory do have a little on-chip SRAM for the use of startup code or software-managed caching.

Comment: Why do you think you need to modify the on-chip boot loader?

Answer (score 1):

There is usually no flash in a Cortex-A. The ROM code is usually, well.., in a Read Only Memory. When there is a bug in this code, you need to produce a new wafer mask to fix it, but, as millions of parts are produced, the cost reduction is significant, and ROM avoid data retention issues.

Comment: Typically unless investing extreme sums in an ASIC, one would keep the internal ROM relatively limited, to loading a 2nd stage bootloader, firmware, and/or operating system from an external modifiable flash chip, SD card, or disk drive.  Mistakes found there are relatively easy to fix before shipping, and with care to an upgrade mechanism potentially possible even afterwards.

Comment: so, is there any chip who's on-chip mask primary bootloader can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Flash memory is by definition re-writable; the parts you mentioned simply have *no* on-chip flash.

Parts that have on-chip flash typically execute code directly from it, so because of the relatively low speed of flash memory it is usually used on lower frequency processors sub-200KHz.

Fast "applications" processors do not normally have on-chip flash because it takes up a large amount of die space and and has insufficient capacity to support the for the kind of applications and OS (such as Linux, Android or Windows) typically used on such processors.  Instead they often have an on-chip mask ROM primary bootloader than loads a secondary bootloader from external media such as NOR flash, NAND flash, SD card, eMMC etc.  The secondary bootloader then boots the OS and/or application code.

Code on such processors is loaded to and executed from SDRAM which is much faster than flash. Also the boot media is not always memory mapped so cannot be executed directly in any case.

Comment: so, is there any chip who's on-chip mask primary bootloader can be changed?

Comment: @ghking : No - just as flash memory is always re-writable, mask ROM is *always* read-only.  You appear to be asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/) - i.e. you think you have a solution to a problem, and you are asking about how to implement the solution.  Instead you should ask about the actual problem - you may get several more practical solutions.  Your stated aim is to "study cortex-A inside", I cannot see how changing the bootstrap code will help in that.